# Ubuntu 14.04 stuck in a login loop, can't boot from a USB and can't use Terminal

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, usb, login

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Idea Pad S12. I am not able to log in as the admin nor the guest. When trying to open Terminal, I only get black-white-blue squares and have to restart the computer. I tried 2 different bootable USB with a different version of Ubuntu and also Linux Mint. I only get a black screen with a flashing underscore. I can't log in, can't insert any commands and can't boot from a USB. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try a liveCD. If you can't boot even a livecd, you need to go to BIOS/UEFI menu and change the boot device order. Choose CD/DVD driver first, then USB or usb-zip, then HDD/SSD. Save changes, exit BIOS/UEFI, and reboot. On some laptops it is enough to just press ESC key at startup and a boot menu will appear asking you what device to boot from.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, Lenovo Idea Pad S12 is a netbook, no CDs.. The order in BIOS has been changed, it did not help.

Comment: Ok, that is odd. Tried 2 different usb drives and 2 different linuxes. So it's not linux fault, nor USB drive fault. Maybe usb port is broken. Have you tried all 3 usb ports?? Maybe an external cd/dvd drive could help with live mode? OR you could try to create a Live(micro)SD card!! You can create it just about the same as a LiveUSB, but without the usb involved, obviously. Card reader is rarely used, so the chances of being broken are slim.

Comment: I checked the specs of Lenovo Idea Pad S12. It's a pretty modest netbook... from 2009. Maybe Ubuntu 14.04 it's too much for it (only 1 GB RAM with some rogue VIA graphic processor). Try Lubuntu (any version) and see what happens. My guess is a very weak graphic processor. It will never be able to run the sophisticated Unity of Ubuntu.